# What do the numbers after area names mean in World of Warcraft maps?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When I zoom out of the map to view the whole continent and hover my mouse over different areas of the map, I see some numbers inside parentheses after the area name e.g. 'Elwynn Forest **(10-20)**', `Darkshire **(20-30)**'. What do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers represent the suggested level range for the zone. Quests and mobs in that area will be tuned for characters within the specified range.

Comment: It's worth noting that once you reach the max recommended level for that zone while leveling, it is better to head into the next zone(unless you really want to complete a quest chain you are doing currently) as quest rewards and experience gained from regular monsters will be higher in the newer zone(as long as the zone level is higher).

Comment: That's what came to my mind also but I wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravekner I have this itch for completing a whole quest chain before moving on to next one. Even when in one zone, I can't go on to any other quest giver until I finish all (currently doable) quests from one giver. :(

Comment: @6packkid oh i know the feeling, first time playing i was the exact same, after you've done the quests once though, and are playing on another toon doing the same quests, you get to the point where you are more worried about leveling than redoing quests you've done before

Comment: The level ranges are also color-coded, such that red is "too high for you" and gray is "too low" and yellow is "just right".

Answer (score -1):

Its the leveling range :) Go to a zone when in your level range!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade and thanks for your input - however as you can see someone has already answered this question (with the same answer of yours), making your post redundant - you might find you get a few downvotes on it. As a rule, only answer questions with an accepted answer if you have something else to say or something to add.